# add/change div wrapper around specific radio button?

Tags: 7, theming, forms

By default, the HTML markup for radio buttons looks like (Drupal 7):

```
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-SOME_ID">
  <input id="edit-SOME_ID" class="form-radio" type="radio" value="SOME_VALUE" name="SOME_NAME" /> 
  <label class="option" for="edit-bla-bla">MY LABEL</label>
</div>
```

I need to change/add some css classes in the outer `<div>` OR add a wrapper `<div>`. How do I do that?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: did you find the answer actually were the same looking for answer for this changing wrapper attributes around each radio button.. please reply.. thanks

Comment: I wonder if you might clarify where the -SOME_ID is coming from in your "by default" Drupal theming of radios. To level the variables, I switched to Seven theme and still see only the ID of the radios group, not a wrapper on each item :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're defining the form yourself you can wrap an element with HTML using the [`#prefix`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#prefix) and [`#suffix`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#suffix) properties:

```
$form['radios'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => 'Options',
  '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(1, 2, 3),
  '#prefix' => '<div class="some-class">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>'
);
```

If you want to add a class to the existing wrapper you can do so using the [`#attributes`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes) property:

```
$form['radios'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => 'Options',
  '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(1, 2, 3),
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('some-class')
  )
);
```

If you're not defining the form yourself then you can still use the same logic and implement a [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to change the existing form:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'some_form_id') {
    $form['some_element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'some-class';
  }
}
```

Note that when using the `hook_form_alter()` method you should append to the existing classes array so as not to override any classes that have been set previously.

Comment: I mean wrapper around each radio button, not group

Comment: This does it for the entire group of radios not the individual radio buttons.

Comment: From your comment, If you wanted around each radio button @volocuga then why, as original poster of the question, did you accept this answer?  Or did this answer do what you actually needed?

Comment: @therobyouknow Good question after 8 years. Sorry I don't recall all details

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this after much work and trying every posted method using a smart tip I found deep in the internet on another site: http://e9p.net/altering-individual-radio-or-checkbox-items-drupal-7-fapi, to use `#after_build` to be able to alter the form element individual radios once they are a drupal render array.

I wanted each radio wrapped in a container with a class, so I used `#prefix` and `#suffix` to do that:

```
function _MYMODULE_options_after_build(&$element, &$form_state){
    // Each renderable radio element.
    foreach (element_children($element) as $key) {
        $element[$key]['#prefix'] = '<div class="class1 class2">';
        $element[$key]['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    }
    // Always return the element to render in after_build callbacks.
    return $element;
}
```

example use:

```
$form['style'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => t('Select your style option'),
        '#options' => $style_options,
        '#default_value' => NULL,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#after_build' => array(
            '_MYMODULE_options_after_build'
        )
);
```

However if you only want the `input` element to have the class you would need to implement the solution I posted on drupal.org at https://api.drupal.org/comment/60197#comment-60197 to allow the #options_attributes to be used correctly for individual options. Re-posting code here:

```
function MYMODULE_element_info_alter(&$info) {
    // You might want more advanced logic here, to replace instead of override altogether,
    // in case other modules have already altered the core info.
    $info['radios']['#process'] = array('safetycal_request_a_quote_process_radios');
}

function MYMODULE_process_radios($element) {
    // for some reason when I take over processing the radios the structure
    // is slightly different than with form_process_radios and it needs to be fixed
    if(isset($element['element'])){
        $element = $element['element'];
    }
    if (count($element ['#options']) > 0) {
        $weight = 0;
        foreach ($element ['#options'] as $key => $choice) {
            // Maintain order of options as defined in #options, in case the element
            // defines custom option sub-elements, but does not define all option
            // sub-elements.
            $weight += 0.001;

            $element += array($key => array());
            // Generate the parents as the autogenerator does, so we will have a
            // unique id for each radio button.
            $parents_for_id = array_merge($element ['#parents'], array($key));
            $element [$key] += array(
                '#type' => 'radio',
                '#title' => $choice,
                // The key is sanitized in drupal_attributes() during output from the
                // theme function.
                '#return_value' => $key,
                // Use default or FALSE. A value of FALSE means that the radio button is
                // not 'checked'.
                '#default_value' => isset($element ['#default_value']) ? $element ['#default_value'] : FALSE,
                // changed below line to use the #options_attributes array
                '#attributes' => $element['#option_attributes'][$key],
                '#parents' => $element ['#parents'],
                '#id' => drupal_html_id('edit-' . implode('-', $parents_for_id)),
                '#ajax' => isset($element ['#ajax']) ? $element ['#ajax'] : NULL,
                '#weight' => $weight,
            );
        }
    }
    return $element;
}
```

example use:

```
$style_options = array(
    'red' => 'Red',
    'green' => 'Green',
    'yellow' => 'Yellow'
);
$style_option_attributes = array(
    'red' => array(
        'class' => array(
                'red-class'
            )
    ),
    'green' => array(
        'class' => array(
                'green-class'
            )
    ),
    'yellow' => array(
        'class' => array(
                'yellow-class'
            )
    )
);
$form['style'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Select your style option'),
    '#options' => $style_options,
    '#option_attributes' => $style_option_attributes,
    '#default_value' => NULL,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => array(
        'class' => array(
            'radio-element-class'
        )
    )
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the above(prefix/suffix) on the items in the options array then you get anything you want around each item.

```
$form['view_mode'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#default_value' => isset($_GET['view'])?$_GET['view']:1,
    '#options' => array(
          1 => '1',
          2 => '2',
          3 => '3',
    ),
  ),
);
$form['view_mode'][1] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div class="first-item container">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>'
);
```

Comment: I want to believe, but this is not doing it for me (D7). Instead, it just stuffs in the prefix+suffix *as a sibling element* immediately preceding the individually div-wrapped options elements. Could it be a typo, and there really is a way?

Comment: Sounds just like you are adding the div to a  none existing option. Think you have to make sure options array values match each other.

Comment: This definitely does what texas-bronius says, adds a separate element at the same level as the radio buttons, not a working solution, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have been able to achieve this is by creating a different form element for each radio, manually pairing up the names using #name and manually setting a value using #attributes. (#value doesn't work for some reason.)

For example:

```
$form['apple'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radio', // Notice no s here; 'radio' not 'radios'
  '#name' => 'fruit', // This will ensure the radios are in the same group
  '#attributes' => array(
       'value' => 'apple', // I know this is bad but it's the only way I could get setting a value to work
       'class' => 'class_here' // This will add class_here to the default wrapper
   ),
  '#prefix' => '<div class="some-class">', // This will prefix the individual radio, wrapper and label
  '#suffix' => '</div>' // This will suffix the individual radio, wrapper and label
);

// Then just repeat with different values

$form['orange'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radio',
  '#name' => 'fruit', // Same name
  '#attributes' => array(
       'value' => 'orange', // Different value
       'class' => 'class_here'
   ),
  '#prefix' => '<div class="some-class">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>'
);

$form['banana'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radio',
  '#name' => 'fruit', // Same name
  '#attributes' => array(
       'value' => 'banana', // Different value
       'class' => 'class_here'
   ),
  '#prefix' => '<div class="some-class">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>'
);
```

This will add a wrapper and class to the individual radio buttons rather than the radio group as the currently accepted answer does.