# radios options separated into different wrappers

Tags: 7, forms

I'm trying to customize a radios field to wrap some of the options into a div.

What the best way to do it?

I had a look to theme_radio but no success on it :(
example:

```
<div id="part1">
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-SOME_ID">
    <input id="edit-SOME_ID" class="form-radio" type="radio" value="SOME_VALUE" name="SOME_NAME" /> 
    <label class="option" for="edit-bla-bla">MY LABEL</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-SOME_ID">
    <input id="edit-SOME_ID" class="form-radio" type="radio" value="SOME_VALUE" name="SOME_NAME" /> 
    <label class="option" for="edit-bla-bla">MY LABEL</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="part2">
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-SOME_ID">
    <input id="edit-SOME_ID" class="form-radio" type="radio" value="SOME_VALUE" name="SOME_NAME" /> 
    <label class="option" for="edit-bla-bla">MY LABEL</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="part3">
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-SOME_ID">
    <input id="edit-SOME_ID" class="form-radio" type="radio" value="SOME_VALUE" name="SOME_NAME" /> 
    <label class="option" for="edit-bla-bla">MY LABEL</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-SOME_ID">
    <input id="edit-SOME_ID" class="form-radio" type="radio" value="SOME_VALUE" name="SOME_NAME" /> 
    <label class="option" for="edit-bla-bla">MY LABEL</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-SOME_ID">
    <input id="edit-SOME_ID" class="form-radio" type="radio" value="SOME_VALUE" name="SOME_NAME" /> 
    <label class="option" for="edit-bla-bla">MY LABEL</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

ANSWER:

See Djouuuuh answers +

```
$output .= drupal_render($element['element'][$i]);
```

if you do this one below it won't work with ajax...

```
$output .= theme('radio', $element['element'][$i]);
```

Comment: There is a similar question already: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23021/add-change-div-wrapper-around-specific-radio-button Would it be useful for your case?

Comment: not really, in the example it adds it for all of them and not a wrapper containing couple of options only

Comment: Can you please give an example of your desired output please?

Comment: I've edited the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you can achieve that with a theme function, specified like this:

```
$element['example'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#title' => t('Example checkboxes'),
  '#options' => $options,
  '#theme' => array('custom_options'),
);
```

And then, you can write down the output just as you want here:

```
function theme_custom_options($element) {
  $output = '<div id="blah">';
  $output .= $element['#options'][0];
  $output .= $element['#options'][1];
  $output .= '</div><div id="blablah">';
  $output .= $element['#options'][2];
  $output .= $element['#options'][3];
  $output .= '</div>';
  // ETC...
  return $output;
}
```

Does it seem correct?

Comment: Sorry I wrote "checkboxes" instead of "radios" of course... :(

Comment: I've tried to do this kind of thing but for obscure reasons the options where disappearing when I was returning the fucntion. (I even copy the theme_radios function into my custom one but same problem) :(

Comment: Have you got Devel installed to debug?

Comment: yes but somehow when I dsm it doesn't show up all the time. Really annoying to debug

Comment: That is wierd. So if you dsm $element in your custom theme function, nothing appears?

Comment: just from time to time :(

Comment: But your form is always displayed without any problem? When your dsm appears, you can see all your options hierarchy array? Is everything correct in there?

Comment: Yes if I don't return anything. I use this as well in the _theme()         return 'custom_radios' => array(
              'render element' => 'element',
        );

Comment: It seems to work now... no idea what happened, but it seems the cache is kind of messing with it.

Comment: Great! Good idea to clear the cache. It is always the cache anyway ;-)

Comment: it's not like I wasn't doing it before.. but when I clear the cache it doesn't show up straight away, I need to refresh the page afterward. Thanks for your help Djouuuuh!

Comment: actually It's not working, it renders everything except the input radio :(  <div radio-id="2" class="region" data-region-id="region-1">
 <img src="http://localhost/main/sites/all/themes/mytheme/flags/Switzerland.png ">
 <span class="region-name">Geneva</span>
 <span class="checkbox-styled"></span>
</div>

Comment: I actually needed this to get the input radio:  $output .= theme('radio', $element[$i]);//to get the input button